# Apache Redirect with space in query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

If a query string contain space , is it possible to redirect to page not found page using .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I know you can escape it in the rule with a '\ ' or '\s' (all space characters) but I am not sure about the %{QUERY_STRING} if that is what you are asking.